# mongodb - match if a group of values from an array is in another given array [with Aggregation]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

I'm looking for a solution since 3 hours and I don't get it yet.

I have the following collection:

```
{text: 'random text 1', indexes:[1,2] },
{text: 'random text 2', indexes:[1,3] },
{text: 'random text 3', indexes:[2,4] },
```

and I would like to have only the documents that have all the index values in a given array like for example `[1,2,4]`

using the example above, I would like to have the following output:

```
{text: 'random text 1', indexes:[1,2] },
{text: 'random text 3', indexes:[2,4] },
```

`[1,2]` is in `[1,2,4]` -> **OK**

`[1,3]` is not in `[1,2,4]` because of 3 -> **Not OK**

`[1,4]` is in `[1,2,4]` -> **OK**

Any idea? thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of this this `$match` stage:

- Using [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) into `$expr`:

```
{
  "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$setIsSubset": ["$indexes",[1,2,4]]
    }
  }
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D7h3nDLBwFN)

- Using `$elemMatch` and double negation (`$not` and `$nin`):

```
{
  "$match": {
    "indexes": {
      "$not": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "$nin": [1,2,4]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aTHG-HVa7Rx)

Comment: Your welcome, also check the update, using `$expr` and `$setIsSubset` seems more clear solution.